# Xamarin Forms - Xamarin.Social

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.social

I am currently using the Xamarin.Social component in xamarin forms and when I try to post to Facebook, it gives me an error stating: Share Error: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden", anyone know why I am getting this error and how to fix it? Also twitter posting works perfectly fine, so its just Facebook.

Thank You

Comment: have you solved this problem ?

Comment: Did you add `Scope = "publish_actions"`?

Answer (score 1):

some Troubleshooting for your issue:

1. You probably already have your ClientID correctly set up. Check it
   again on  https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. It took me a while to figure out what to enter as for the
       RedirectURL. At the moment i am using
       https://apps.facebook.com/yourappname/. If this is not working for you, go to your App on Facebook Developers Page > Settings > Add Platform > Facebook Canvas > And enter this url as for the "Canvas Page". Authentication should work fine now, and the 403 error should no longer occur.

My working example, for creating the Facebook service:

```
    public static FacebookService Facebook
    {
        get
        {
            if (mFacebook == null)
            {
                mFacebook = new FacebookService() {
                    ClientId = "<Your App ID from https://developers.facebook.com/apps>",
                    RedirectUrl = new Uri ("https://apps.facebook.com/yourappname/")
                };
            }

            return mFacebook;
        }
    }
```

For which Platform are you developing?
The rest of the share process is just like in the Xamarin.Social IOS Unified sample.
Don‘t hesitate to ask for clarification.